# Bazel/Golang: rule 'go_embed_data' doesn't contain declared provider 'GoArchive'

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to create a Bazel rule for my project that just embeds a collection of files. The embed rule is as follows:

```py
go_embed_data(
    name = "my_files_go",
    src = [
        "embedded/src1", "embedded/src2"
    ],
    package = "my_lib",
    var = "myFiles",
)
```

Which I then add in my go_library rule:

```py
go_library(
    name = "library",
    srcs = [
        "library.go",
    ],
    importpath = "github.com/nickfelker/golang-app",
    deps = [
        ":my_files_go"
        "//otherLib",
    ],
)
```

However when I try to build this, I end up getting an obscure error that I cannot find elsewhere.

```
Error: <target //library:my_files_go> (rule 'go_embed_data') doesn't contain declared provider 'GoArchive'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:binary' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//library:library' failed
```

How am I supposed to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule created for `go_embed_data` does not go as a dependency to the `go_library` rule. Instead, it should be considered one of the `srcs`, as so:

```py
go_embed_data(
    name = "my_files_go",
    src = [
        "embedded/src1", "embedded/src2"
    ],
    package = "my_lib",
    var = "myFiles",
)

go_library(
    name = "library",
    srcs = [
        ":my_files_go",
        "library.go",
    ],
    importpath = "github.com/nickfelker/golang-app",
    deps = [
        "//otherLib",
    ],
)
```